# DataGridView columns disappears after set custom ColumnType

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I've created a custom IDataGridViewEditingControl (and related column and cell). When I choose this type in the Edit Columns dialog and click on OK button all the columns in the datagridview will be disappeared. The form.Designer.cs file won't contains any column so my idea is that an exception occurs during the code generation but the designer hide it.

I tried to debug with help of another instance of VS (Debug / Attach to process: devenv.exe) but I couldn't find the problem in my code. Is there any way to get the exception from? Is there any detaileg VS log where I can find these hidden exceptions?

Environment is VS2013 (tried with Express for Desktop and Professional)

Thanks,
Loti

Comment: Have you any code in your custom Column/Cell/Editor implemented or overriden methods? Sure :)  Start with disabling any code in these methods (you should return appropriate values of course); if this way column editor starts to behave correctly, enable your code method by method to find out, which method exactly crashes.

Comment: You'll need to find a site where psychics give out free advice when you don't show us your code.

Comment: @HansPassant: Unfortunately the code is too large to share. 
I've duple (triple and more) checked it manually. I'm not a noob so you can believe me: it isn't contains any trivial error. 
The main question is how can i find the wrong part of the code if the closed source (.net datagridview) of a component hide it in design time?

Comment: @Arvo: It's a good idea. I'll try it if better idea or solution won't come. There are too many overrided and extended methods used in this control / column and the cell editor is based a custom control also (which working well outside from the grid) so this way is too long. I hope somebody else has a trick to catch the exception

Comment: Create dummy custom editor (only with required implementation) first and use it instead of your editor - this way you at least will narrow your problem area to editor or to column/cell implementation. We initally had also some similar problems with custom grid/column/cell/editor, but our problems lied mostly in grid methods overrides (it fires quite many kind of events in designer).